# Dot Product to Calculate a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Use dot products to find an equation of the plane $Γ$ that passes through $Q = (1,−19,−1)$ parallel to the plane $4 x − 7 y + 9z = −54$

I am assuming I have to find a plane that is a multiple of that plane?

Thus the answer:

```
4(x - 1) - 7(y + 19) + 9(z + 1) = 0
```

Comment: This is right, and probably you are expected to explain this answer using a dot product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Here's an explanation.

Recall that two planes are parallel if their normal vectors are parallel.
So the plane in questions has as a (possible) normal vector $\vec{n} = (4,-7,9)$.

Now let $P = (x,y,z)$ be any point in this plane. The the vector $\vec{QP}= (x-1,y+19,z+1)$ lines in this plane as well, and is orthogonal to $\vec{n}$.

This orthogonality means that

$$0 = \vec{n} \cdot \vec{QP} = 4(x - 1) - 7(y + 19) + 9(z + 1).$$

Since $P$ was chosen arbitrarily in the plane, the equation

$$4(x - 1) - 7(y + 19) + 9(z + 1)=0 $$

is satisfied by any point on the plane, and is therefore the equation of the plane itself.